# pulling variable into the data of AJAX post function

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, post

I have the below function call and I am trying to pull the value of the variable data into the data: section of the function. I have gotten this far but no such luck getting it to work.
In php I am using $_POST['test'] to try an pull the value.

THanks

```
function fnc()
 {
   var oButton = document.getElementById("addData");
   var data = document.getElementById("dataInput");
   var display = document.getElementById("display");


     display.innerHTML += "<a id='dispchk'>"+ data.value +"</a>" +"<br />" ;
}
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "chkinpost.php?eventid=<?php echo $_GET['eventid']; ?>&eventname=<?php echo $_GET['eventname']; ?>",
    data: "test="+ data.value
});
```

Comment: Your `data` variable is only in the scope of the `fnc` function.

Comment: data: {test: data.value}

Comment: @PeterM: You can pass `data` either an object *or* a query string.

Comment: @RocketHazmat Ok, how can i get it in scope?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either don't use the `function fnc()`:

```
var oButton = document.getElementById("addData");
var data = document.getElementById("dataInput");
var display = document.getElementById("display");
display.innerHTML += "<a id='dispchk'>"+ data.value +"</a>" +"<br />" ;
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "chkinpost.php?eventid=<?php echo $_GET['eventid']; ?>&eventname=<?php echo $_GET['eventname']; ?>",
    data: "test="+ data.value
});
```

*or* move your AJAX request into `function fnc()`:

```
function fnc()
{
  var oButton = document.getElementById("addData");
  var data = document.getElementById("dataInput");
  var display = document.getElementById("display");
  display.innerHTML += "<a id='dispchk'>"+ data.value +"</a>" +"<br />" ;
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "chkinpost.php?eventid=<?php echo $_GET['eventid']; ?>&eventname=<?php echo $_GET['eventname']; ?>",
    data: "test="+ data.value
  });
}
```

Comment: thanks buddy.  I needed to keep the function so I used the 2nd option.

Answer (score 0):

[Either pass a **string** or a **plain object** as data parameter](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/)

```
var url = "chkinpost.php?eventid=<?php echo $_GET['eventid']; ?>&eventname=<?php echo $_GET['eventname']; ?>"

//var data = { value: "some value"}
//or
var data = 'this is a chicken';

$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: url,
  data: data,
});
```